# str.replace_all() using regex

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a rather simple task.

say i have a column called `path`, it looks something like this:

```py
pl.Series('path', ['[1, Phone], [2, Tablet], [3, Tablet], [4, Phone], [5, Phone], [6, Phone]'])
```

i'd like to replace the commas between blocks with hyphen (`-`).

```py
[1, Phone]-[2, Tablet]-[3, Tablet]-[4, Phone]-[5, Phone]-[6, Phone]
```

I tried the following using this pattern `[a-z]\](,)\s` so `(,)` is a capturing group.
however, this doesn't work, since it replaces the entire pattern.

-- consider the column as part of a df.

```py
with_columns(pl.col('path').str.replace_all(r'[a-z]\](,)\s', '-'))
```

Am I missing something? i'd appreciate any input or idea!

Comment: I'm guessing there should be quotes around your example? `pl.Series('path', ['[1, Phone]...']` i.e. you have a string value?

Comment: Making some DSVs eh?  Another thing you can do is terminate the use of special characters so that you can include commas in your strings.

Comment: This is not really a regex problem.  A normal string replace of `s.replace('], [','] - [')` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like perhaps you are under the impression that only the capture group is replaced?

The main use of the capture group is to use in the replacement side, so you capture the parts you want to keep.

In this case, whatever comes before the comma:

```
s = pl.Series('path', ['[1, Phone], [2, Tablet], [3, Tablet], [4, Phone], [5, Phone], [6, Phone]'])

s.str.replace_all(r'([a-z]\]),\s', '$1-')
```

```
shape: (1,)
Series: 'path' [str]
[
    "[1, Phone]-[2, Tablet]-[3, Tablet]-[4, Phone]-[5, Phone]-[6, Phone]"
]
```

`$1` is replaced with the contents of capture group 1.

Polars syntax for this follows the underlying rust library:

https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#replacement-string-syntax

Comment: you're right. seems like i had the wrong impression of the capturing group. I wasn't aware of how to use the capture groups correctly and its `$` notation. thanks!

Comment: It's actually an interesting idea, sometimes it can be easier to specify what you want to keep instead of specifying what you want to remove/modify. I've added a link to the rust docs which polars uses for regex which has more information. (e.g. named groups, etc.)